# Grant privileges to all users mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, sql-grant

Actually i am making  java app...and it is creating a database and table in the database on the first run..now i want it to grant select,create,insert on that table to all the users present in mysql..and even if a new user is created it should have privileges on that table too...i have tried alot of stuff from the internet heres the queries i have tried executing

```
grant select,create,insert on db.table to PUBLIC
grant select,create,insert on db.table to ''@'%'
grant select,create,insert on db.able to '*'@'%'
```

please help me with it...
this is my javacode for the creation of database and table on the first run

```
st=conn.createStatement();

            ResultSet r=conn.getMetaData().getCatalogs();boolean dbe=false;
            while(r.next())
            {
                if(r.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase("DB"))
                    {
                        st.execute("use db");
                        dbe=true;
                    }
            }
            if(!dbe)
            {
                st.execute("create database db");
                st.execute("use db");
                st.execute("create table tab(name varchar(255),address varchar(80),at datetime)");
            }
```

Comment: You should tag your question with the appropriate language you are using.

Comment: did you try.. GRANT ALL on \*.\* to 'user'@'%';

Comment: you want to give permission on specific table to specific user or all users can have rights on all tables of that db and also do you want to give global permissions or just from some specific ip.

Comment: Chella, but that will grant all privileges to user on all databases and tables on any remote server....i want all users even the users created after the creation of database db and table tab to be able to select,insert on db.tab

Comment: @ZafarMalik i want to give permission on db.tab to all users existing or created in future..premissions i want to give are select,insert on db.tab on any remote server not on a specific ip

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/47429/28450

Comment: @Eez thanks man thats a really good work around

Comment: @AnshSahajpal welcome bro

Answer (score -2):

For granting privileges to all database:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON .* TO 'myuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

For granting privileges to a specific database:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'myuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: This does not answer the question -- it will only grant permission to `myuser`, whereas the asker wants to grant it to _all_ users...